# Services 3 and node locations

Tags: nodes, services

I'm trying to create a node via services 3 in Drupal 7. The node os created, but when I try to pass the location parameters in, it does not work. If I pass an lid that already exists, it seems to reference that location; if I try to pass a new lid, the information is not registered.

Is there such thing as a location resource for the services module? THis is the JSON string I am using.

```
{
"title":"test",
"type":"test_type",
"locations":[
      {
         "lid":"4",
         "name":"",
         "street":"",
         "additional":"",
         "city":"",
         "province":"",
         "postal_code":"",
         "country":"us",
         "latitude":"40.663062",
         "longitude":"-73.969760",
         "source":"1",
         "is_primary":"0",
          "locpick":{
            "user_latitude":"40.663061",
            "user_longitude":"-73.969760"
         },
         "province_name":"",
         "country_name":"United States"
      }
   ],
}
```

Comment: If you print_r the form when you submit it via a regular drupal submission, what does the node object look like?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, where should I insert the statment? I tried creating a small module 'function sitehelper_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    dpr($form);
}' it printed out a node like this http://pastie.org/2848203

Comment: thats the whole node object? looks more like a comment object.

Comment: ok, let me try that again, here is the entire $form object that is being submitted (the node object is within that I believe). The odd thing is that if I provide a new, distinct lid under locations in the JSON call, it seems to create a location with the correct lid, but it does not seem to grab the latitude or longitude http://pastie.org/2849875 .... thanks by the way for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
var node = {
                title: "Sample Location",
                body: { 
                    und: [{
                          value: 'Sample Body'
                          }]
                },
                field_location_type: {
                    und: [{
                          latitude : '37.4861987023',  
                          longitude : '-122.2312',
                          country_name : 'United States',
                          province : 'CA',
                          city: 'My City',
                          postal_code : '12345',
                          name : 'Place Name',
                          }]
                },
                type: 'location',
                language: 'und',
            };
```

This sets a variable 'node' for Javascript. CCK field is "location_type". All the other parameters are being inserted into the node (city, postal_code,...) , but the Lat/Lon is still not being posted. I suspect that it may be because a node can have many 'locations'. Any help here would be great.

Take a look at the debug log: admin/reports/dblog for the json interaction. You need to turn on Services Debug "Debug mode enabled" located at admin/structure/services/list/api where 'api' is the endpoint.